# Highcharts: Updating a Pie Chart with setData()

Tags: json, highcharts

I am trying to work out how to update a Highcharts pie chart but for the life of me cannot seem to get it working right.

I have looked over the documentation and have been able to get a bar and line and spline graph to update fine but when using this function for pie charts it just does not work.

I am currently feeding in:

```
item.setData([["none", 100]], true);
```

Where item equals the series like so:

```
$.each(browser_chart.series, function(i, item){
    if(item.name == 'Browser share'){
        console.log(data.browsers);
        item.setData([["none", 100]], true);
    }
});
```

Which as shown in the demos is how the data for a pie chart is formatted. Problem is it cannot seem to read the series correctly. I try:

```
item.setData([\"none\", 100], true);
```

And it seems to do something but cannot read the x and y values right (which of course means it's wrong).

Can anyone here point me in the direction to get this working?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edited:**
When you set a new data you have to set as array of arrays for all pie parts in this case.
In my [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/SzuPB/4/) I have six categories, so I've to set data for all of them.

So, in this case you have to do something like:

```
var seriesData = [];
$.each(browser_chart.series, function(i, item) {
    if(item.name == 'Browser share'){
        seriesData.push(["serie"+i, someNumber]);
    }
});
chart.series[0].setData(seriesData, true);
```

Comment: Hmm that didn't work but your example did tell me why. When I update the pie chart I actually miss out points in the series because some browsers don't have a value for a date range my user has selected. It seems when I update with less points than I originally had it cannot seem to update properly and throws a nasty error. Do you know of anyway around this?

Comment: I have been able to get this working with different points by remaking the pie chart with new Highcharts.Chart() but it is kinda ugly, is this the only way to do it do you know?

Answer (score 0):

I have marked Ricardos answer however my question involved a tad more that I didn't explain properly.

I was updating the pie chart through AJAX from JSON generated by a PHP Backend. When I applied new data to the pie chart it would break.

Using Ricardos answer I was able to find out it is because I have a different number of points so I cannot just update the pie chart I must remake it like so:

```
browser_chart_config.series[0].data = data.browsers;
browser_chart = new Highcharts.Chart(browser_chart_config);
```

This will allow you to update a chart when you have a different number of points.

Hope it helps,

EDIT: I also found out that this is a known issue with HighCharts: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/542

Comment: It works only when you set all serie data, so in your case you have to destroy the chart and do it again. :/

Answer (score -1):

```js
 //initialise
        var new_data;
            new_data = [{ name: 'load percentage', y: 10.0, color: '#b2c831' },{ name: 'rest', y: 60.0, color: '#3d3d3d' }];
 function requestData() 
        {             
   $.ajax({
    url: 'live-server-data.php', 
    success: function(point) 
                                {
     var series = chart.series[0];
                                        var y_val = parseInt(point[1]);                                      
                                        var x_val = 100 - y_val;
                                        console.log(point[0]+ "," +point[1] );//["0"]
                                        new_data = [{ name: 'load percentage', y:y_val, color: '#b2c831' },{ name: 'rest', y:x_val, color: '#3d3d3d' }];                                                                
                                        series.setData(new_data);                                   
                                        // call it again after one second     
    },
    cache: false
   });
 }
```

Comment: You should add a description of the solution you are proposing.