# Highcharts Series [DATA]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Highcharts for drawing my Piecharts. My problem is with Series. `data[]`
am passing data to the Series `data[]` static way, now the situation is like is i want to send data dynamically to Jquery. I am unable to understand **how?**

My data is like:

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Percentage',
    data: [
        ['Holy',   rr1],
        ['Molly',    rr3],
    ]
}]
```

I want to enter data Jolly now, instead of going to the jquery and giving the data for jolly
can i send directly from the code. BTW am using PHP .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131774/highcharts-updating-a-pie-chart-with-setdata

Comment: please help here man i want ur suggestions  to complete my task